# Changing password seems to fail in asp.net mvc3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm programming the option to change a password in asp.net mvc 3 and I have the following code for the account controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CambiarContraseña(CambioContraseña model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
        // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
        bool cambioContraseñaCorrecto = true;
        try
        {
            MembershipUser usuarioActual = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
            cambioContraseñaCorrecto = usuarioActual.ChangePassword(model.ContraseñaVieja, model.ContraseñaNueva);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            cambioContraseñaCorrecto = false;
        }
        if (cambioContraseñaCorrecto)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CambioContraseñaCorrecto");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "La actual contraseña es inválida o la nueva contraseña es incorrecta.");
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

The problem is the bool var "CambioContraseñaCorrecto" always is false I don't understand why is that. So always when I test, the app prints me the message of ModelStat and doesn't work the change of the password. Any solution?

Comment: What is your Membership Provider?

Comment: Not very sure, but please have a look at the link [membershipuser-changepassword-fails-for-one-user-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001496/c-sharp-membershipuser-changepassword-fails-for-one-user-only) Just see, if it helps,in case you haven't seen it before.

Comment: Either your provider is always returning false, or you're getting an exception and setting your flag to false. BTW, don't ever do that -  you need to know what the exception is, if you get one.